# Order of execution for OnPaint/OnPaintBackground for a collection of controls

Tags: .net, winforms

Assume you have a container control (say, form) with a collection of other controls inside it. The child controls may be arranged as a hierarchy, i.e. some of the child controls are nested in other child controls (parent, child, grand-child, and so on...).

1. Then, what is the order of execution for `OnPaint` and `OnPaintBackground` methods for parent, child, (and grand-child) controls?
2. And how does `Invalidate` fit in here?

Comment: Windows uses the painter's algorithm.  Back to front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans is correct - back to front. So the parent will be drawn first, then the children. Children will be drawn in reverse order of ChildIndex, which can be obtained using `parent.GetChildIndex(child)`. A child index of 0 is on top, so the highest child index will be drawn first, and child index 0 will be drawn last.

Drawing is done depth-first, so all children/grandchildren of one control are drawn before the next control is drawn.

`Control.Invalidate()` causes the entire bounding box for the control to be redrawn, so `OnPaint` will be called for the control and its children. Note that `OnPaint` will execute asynchronously, so your code will continue running without waiting for the paint to complete.

Comment: Small clarification: _A child index of 0 is on top, so the highest child index will be drawn first._ If we consider the depth of the graphics, control with child index 0 will be underneath every sibling?

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh.aspx - child index 0 will be above everything. So if you have 3 child controls, index 2 (the bottom control) will be drawn first, index 1 will be drawn second, and index 0 will be drawn third.

Comment: Thanks, I missinterpreted the part _so the highest child index will be drawn first_, hence the confusion.